# How to get what a jar prints

Tags: java, jar

Ok im making a program in java that starts another jar. How would i read everything that jar prints out when it uses System.out.println() or any errors it prints out?

Comment: Define start. You load the JAR and invoke a method in it or you spawn a new JVM with that JAR?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using either `ProcessBuilder.start()` or `Runtime.exec()` to "start the other jar", both of which return a `Process` object. Calling `getInputStream()` on this instance will give you an `InputStream` that represents stdout. Calling `getErrorStream()` gives you stderr.